# What should i do to run PL/SQL on sql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[PL/SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cukF.png)

```
[set serveroutput on;
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello world');
end;]
```

/
(code is executing but output in not showing)

Comment: Do you have the DBMS Output window in SQL Developer open?  Did you enable DBMS Output via the GUI?

Comment: yes sir it is opened.....i also run [SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;] still no output

Comment: You realize it is not open in the image you posted, correct?  Your `set serveroutput on` is also after the PL/SQL block that tries to generate the output.

Answer (score 1):

On oracle SQL Developer it is often needed to just turn the output on

The short answer would be: you need to click on green plus sign on the output window

[image: enabling output on oracle sql developer]

See [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/enabling-dbms_output-by-default-in-sql-developer/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @ekochergin is correct, but I never use that. It is very convenient to just use the script output window. SQLDeveloper has a feature called code templates (code snippets on older versions), which allow to bring up some code just by typing a few letters and invoke it. Create a code template for

```
set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
```

The clear screen clears the previous output so you don't have to scroll.

I'm on a mac and for me getting the dbms output for a pl/sql call is just a couple of keystrokes:

- "so" (that is my code template for server output)
- option-space to expand the code snippet
- ctrl-enter to run my code with the output in the Script Output window